# How To Disable ECSlidingViewController pangesture when the width of the LeftMenuView is fully revealed?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm able to make the `ECSlidingViewController` implementations works fine already.
But I'm getting a hard time how to solve this scenario.

Okay, I have the `MainViewController` and a `LeftMenuViewController`,
My `MainViewController` width is 320 and my `LeftMenuViewController` width is 240 and
Both their heights are the full view (depends whether 3.5 or 4 inch iPhone screen)

I'm able to reveal the `LeftMenuButton` via "Reveal" button from my `MainViewController`, and/or via `self.slidingViewController.panGesture`. Actually, it works fine!

My problem is, I want to stop the said gesture when the whole width of `LeftMenuView` (which is 240) is already exposed. Cause as of this moment, I can swipe up to the rightmost edge of my view, Exposing the `LeftMenuView` plus extra 80 white space at the right.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of `ECSlidingViewController` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using v1.x of `ECSlidingViewController`, you should be setting the `anchorLeftRevealAmount` and `anchorRightRevealAmount` values and then setting `shouldAllowPanningPastAnchor` to `NO` to prevent scroll past the anchor values.

Comment: Thanks! It works! Mind if I ask you another question?

Comment: Please tick the answer if it's correct. I don't mind, but you may be better served creating a new question...

Comment: Ticked already, can you answer this question of mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225037/how-to-properly-set-the-radius-of-clregion