# How to properly set the Radius of CLRegion?

Tags: ios7, cllocationmanager, geofencing, clregion

This is my code for creating a geofence:

```
Geofence *geofence = [[Geofence alloc] init];
[geofence setRadius:100.0];
[geofence setIdentifier: @"Fence1"];
[geofence setLocation:currentlocation];


CLRegion *region1 =  [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:[geofence.location coordinate]
                                               radius:geofence.radius
                                               identifier:geofence.identifier];

region1.notifyOnEntry=YES;
region1.notifyOnExit=YES;
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region1];
```

I could say that, the above code works, meaning the geofence have been created. But there's a problem I've been encountering.

I have a .gpx files (in which I will be using for simulation of my current location), their distances from the center of the region/geofence are as follows: 55m, 90m, 150m, 200m, 300m, 500m, 1Km, 5Km and 10Km.

My problem is, its seems that my geofence radius is not really 100m, because when I simulate using gpx files whose distance from the center of the geofence are 55m, 90m, 150, 200m, 300m, 500m, 1km. The delegate methods of `LocationManager -didEnterRegion` and `-didExitRegion` is making a respond that I'm within my Geofence whose radius is just "100m".

Only the gpx files with distances from my geofence center that are 5Km and 10km responds from the said delegate methods that I'm outside the Geofence.

Can you help me resolve this scenario guys?

[image]

Comment: Have you sanity checked the values the region is created with and the locations of your test data? Have you tried 2KM?

Comment: Yes, the test data are all correct, I edited my question. I added a screen shot of the application. I created an overlay with 100m radius, the same value of CLRegion Radius. Look at the simulated current location. It's the gpx file which is around 1KM away from my geofence. But the CLLocationManeger's -didEnterRegion and -didExitRegion is telling me that I'm within my geofence (whose radius is just 100m). Any thoughts?

Comment: The radius of your overlay came from the region being monitored? I haven't seen this kind of issue when simulating, hence the sanity checking questions...

Comment: Since geofence in iOS is defined as imaginary circular region within your map, just to have a visual view, I created an overlay with same value (same center coordinates, and same radius value) to that of my CLRegion, which is 100.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that you are using the same variables to initialize your region with as the ones you are using to initialize your geofence as far as their center coordinates are concerned. Thus one always thinks its within the other.